# How to list all documents in an RxDB collection?

Tags: rxdb

In RxDB, to list all documents in a collection on a remote db that has documents, I've tried:

```js
 myCollection.dump()
  .then(json => console.dir(json));
```

and

```js
myCollection.find().exec() // <- find all documents
  .then(documents => console.dir(documents));
```

from the documentation: https://rxdb.info/rx-collection.html#dump
https://rxdb.info/rx-document.html#find

but both do a `_find` post with body:

```
{"selector":{"_id":{}}}
```

that return an empty docs [] array. That same `_find` selector executed outside of RxDB also returns an empty docs array.

If I add documents to the collection with `myCollection.upsert()`, the doc is added to the remote server and then appears as a response in the two above calls. But maybe only from what's stored in memory, as there's still this remote `_find` POST with an empty `docs: []` response. So on a page refresh those list calls are empty again.

I'm using:

```
    "pouchdb-adapter-http": "7.0.0",
    "rxdb": "8.0.4",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point of time, there is no RxDB support for remote collections.
You can sync the remote database into your local collection and then run queries there. But it is not possible to send queries to remote and get the results, like what is done with pouchdb-http-adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can head on to rxdb.info since the major version release 9.0.0 has announced several improvements in querying the document fields in a better way